# How can one prepare oneself to receive a slap in a slapping contest?

Tags: defense

I wonder what the techniques are to prepare oneself to receive a slap in a [slapping contest](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Slapping_(strike)&oldid=1132731391#Slapping_contests) (e.g., "[Power Slap League](https://twitter.com/powerslapleague)"). I read techniques to improve the slap but didn't find any yet on the best way to receive it.

Comment: I strongly advise against participating in slapping contests. You will put yourself at rick of Chronic Traumatic  Encephalopathy (a form of brain damage), and other injuries to the beck and eardrums.

Comment: @Futilitarian I agree. Regarding CTEs, true for many sports:  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5094259/ "It is estimated that between 1.6 and 3.8 million sports-related mTBIs occur annually, and sport-related head injuries make up 20% of TBI cases in the United States each year \[[10](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5094259/#b10-jvin-9-2-7),[11](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5094259/#b11-jvin-9-2-7)\]. This may be an underestimate, as mTBI frequently goes unreported." But esp. fighting + US football. Hence my interest in defense.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Power Slap president Frank Lamicella [mentioned the following defense](https://twitter.com/JohnMorgan_MMA/status/1617911478085894145):

> There is definitely defense. There is training the head, neck, shoulder muscles, and our sports science and sports data that we put out will start to support that.

Reddit Head catcher [onejonejohnson](https://www.reddit.com/user/bonejonejohnson) [mentioned the following defense](https://redd.it/10gk5d5):

> Tensing the neck, clenching the jaw.